# How to read 2 lines separately in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first question here!

I have a file contains hundreds of lines such as:

```
<car> <part_of> <machine>     
<motor> <part_of> <car>
```

Each line represents subject, relation, object

I want to read each 2 lines separately, process them, then output 2 or 3 lines based on the input file.
I did something like this:

```
    opener = open('input.txt')        # to read even lines
    opener2 = open('input.txt')       # to read odd lines
    num = 2
    for eachline in opener:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            line1 = opener.readline().split()
            sub_line1, rel_line1, obj_line1 = line1[0],line1[1],line1[2]
            sub_line1 = line1[0].lstrip("<").rstrip(">")
            rel_line1 = line1[1].lstrip("<").rstrip(">")
            obj_line1 = line1[2].lstrip("\"").rstrip("\"")
        else:
            line2 = opener2.readline().split()
            sub_line2, rel_line2, obj_line2 = line1[0],line2[1],line2[2]
            sub_line2 = line2[0].lstrip("<").rstrip(">")
            rel_line2 = line2[1].lstrip("<").rstrip(">")
            obj_line2 = line2[2].lstrip("\"").rstrip("\"")
        num += 1
```

And I did this for the output:

```
output1 = " ".join([sub_line1,rel_line1,obj_line1])
writer.write(output1+"\n")
output2 = " ".join([sub_line2,rel_line2,obj_line2])
writer.write(output2+'\n')
output3 = " ".join([sub_line1,relation,sub_line2])
writer.write(output3+'\n')
```

Note: output3 does not exist in the input. I am adding this by combining the previous 2 lines. But every time the odd lines rewritten by the even one. How can I separate them ?

sample output:

```
<car> <part_of> <machine>
<motor> <part_of> <car>
<car> <part_of> <motor>
```

each 3rd line is composed based on the previous 2 lines.

**PART 2:**

If there is a line in the input file, starts with "_" how can I just output it as it is without including it as one of the 2 lines I am processing? where can I put this condition?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the significance of even and odd lines? In your example they look the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get a file descriptor (the stuff returned by `open`) to read only odd or even lines.
It has to read the whole content of the file<sup>1</sup>.

However and therefore, you do not need to have two file descriptors: you can do the job with only one.
You can iterate over `enumerate(file)` instead of `file`.
Instead of giving you the lines, it will give you `(index, line)` couples.
You can unpack this by doing `for id, line in enumerate(file)`, and then check the remainder of `id` by `2` to determine if it's odd or even.

```
file = open(path, 'r')
for id, line in enumerate(file):
    if id % 2 == 0:
        # The line is even
    else:
        # The line is odd
```

---

<sup>1</sup>To be fair, you *could* get a file descriptor to read only odd or even lines, in that you could just skip every other line... But then, why bother to create two descriptors when a single one is already doing the job?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you need to separate iterators; just read two lines at a time:

```
with open('input.txt') as fh:
    while True:
        line1 = fh.readline()
        line2 = fh.readline()
        if not line1:
            break
        ...
```

The condition under which you break can be modified to break if *both* `line1` and `line2` are empty, such as if the file has an odd number of lines.

However, if you *do* need the separate iterators for some reason, make each iterator take care of skipping every other line. Use the `itertools` module to make this easy:

```
from itertools import tee, islice, izip
with open('input.txt') as fh:
    # Get two copies of the iterator. IMPORTANT: don't use fh
    # anymore; only itr1 and itr2
    itr1, itr2 = tee(fh)

    itr1 = islice(itr1, 0, None, 2) # 0, 2, 4, ...
    itr2 = islice(itr2, 1, None, 2) # 1, 3, 5, ...

    for line1, line2 in izip(itr1, itr2):
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help. I did as you said without using itertools. I used you first way. Then I print (line1). It is empty. It is not reading anything.